# How Much VRAM do I need for normal computing and games?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, vram

How Much VRAM do I need for normal computing and games? I have a GeForce gt 610 and the games I'm playing well let just I have to play them on low settings i.e. Armored Warfare. I'm not looking to play this and the crew on High or ultra setting I'm just looking to play to lease make the games playable.

Comment: You need as much as the program requires.  There is no possible way for us to answer this question.  There are applications that require upwards of 8 GB of VRAM just to run without problems, and will use twice that, if provided it.

Comment: Your question is no different than asking "How much gas do I need to drive?"

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on the resolutions of textures. Texture resolution impacts visual quality a lot but you can still reduce it in most games.

For normal computing you need around 512MB as of 2016.

For gaming you need equal to or above 1GB